# Reciting Shema In The Afternoon

Tags: zemanim, mistakes, shema, mincha-afternoon-prayer

If one missed the time of the boqer shema, but it’s time to recite Mincha, should they say the Shema then Mincha, or just recite Mincha?

Answer (score 1):

In Orach Chaim (58:7), it says that in such a case, there is an opinion that one should say a second Shema after Ma’ariv, and the Mishnah Berurah (58:27) says that it is also good to say it sometime during the day as well, and that he must recite a verse that mentions the Exodus.